# Add multiple js files on runtime in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, php, html, asp.net, css

I want to add multiple .js file in my ASP.NET c# page at run time on button click.

```
Literal link2 = new Literal();
Literal link3 = new Literal();
Literal link4 = new Literal();

link2.Text = "<script src=\"Theme1/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js\" type=\"text/javascript\" />";
link3.Text = "<script src=\"Theme1/js/supersized.3.2.7.min.js\" type=\"text/javascript\" />";
link4.Text = "<script src=\"Theme1/js/supersized-init.js\" type=\"text/javascript\" />";

base.Page.Header.Controls.Add(link2);
base.Page.Header.Controls.Add(link3);
base.Page.Header.Controls.Add(link4);
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with? It's not clear from your question what you are asking. Also, why the `php` tag?

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to use RegisterStartupScript method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx

**EXAMPLE :**

```
string jsBlock = "<script src='myJsFile.js'></script>";
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("myJsInclude"))
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "myJsInclude", jsBlock, false);
```

OR

And even better in your case RegisterClientScriptInclude:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx145dw2.aspx

**EXAMPLE**

```
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("myJsInclude"))
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("myJsInclude", "myJsFile.js");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            HtmlLink css3 = new HtmlLink();
            css3.Href = "theme2/css/style.css";
            css3.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
            css3.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
            css3.Attributes["media"] = "all";
            Page.Header.Controls.Add(css3);
```